# jquery function stops working when changing page using Kaminari

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I have this simple function to highlight the clicked row in a table. I have pagination implemented with Kaminari, and the problem is that the function stops working when changing the page. I don't get any error, the row just don't get highlighted.

`app/javascript/table.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table-master tr").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
    $("#table-master tr").removeClass("highlight");
    if (!selected) $(this).addClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

The table gets rendered as a partial here:

`index.html.erb`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <%= render '/shared/form_search', locals: {parts: @parts} %>
  <div id="data-variant"></div>
  <%= render partial: '/shared/table', locals: {parts: @parts} %>
<%= paginate @parts%>
```

Comment: Are you using an ajax call or turbolinks?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but turbolinks are active. I'm not using remote:true to paginate, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If turbolinks is active try using the `"turbolinks:load"` event instead. This events triggers on the initial page load and navigation with turbolinks.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $("#table-master tr").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
    $("#table-master tr").removeClass("highlight");
    if (!selected) $(this).addClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

See: [Building Your Turbolinks Application](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#building-your-turbolinks-application)

Comment: For this issue in particular checkout the installing JavaScript segment. https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior